# Как сделать массовую проверку?

Tags: php, if

Здравствуйте. Нужна массовая проверка) Решил сделать это через условие

```
if () {

}
```

Можно ли сделать так?

```
if ($a, $b, $c, $d == null) {

}
```

Если нет, то как будет правильнее?

Comment: Не сразу заметил комментарий, поэтому написал было ответ с isset. Считаю его более правильно использовать. )

Comment: На наличие переменной используйте isset(), а доя проверки на пустоту и 0 используйте empty()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратный случай решался бы очень просто: `isset($a, $b, $c, $d)` даст `true` только в том случае, если все четыре переменные заданы и не равняются `null`.

---

Пришедшие из формы данные никогда не будут `null` (ну, за исключением неотмеченных чекбоксов/радиокнопок). Они будут пустыми строками. В этом случае поможет

```
if (!$a && !$b && !$c && !$d)
```

Чекбоксы при этом лучше проверять через `isset()` или `empty()`:

```
if (!$textarea && !$input && empty($radio) && !isset($checkbox))
```